# Ruby - undefined local variable

Tags: ruby

I am not quite sure what I am missing. Thanks for the help in advance!

```
# Example:
# encoded_string = "m1i1s2i1s2i1p2i1"
# decoded_string = decode(encoded_string)
# decoded_string # => "mississippi"

# decode("f1o2d1")
# "food"

def decode(string)
  new_str = ""
  i = 0
  while i < string.length
    letter = string[i]
    num = string[i + 1]
    num.times {new_str += letter}
    i += 2
  end
  return new_str
end
```

Comment: It helps us a lot if you include the code in the body of your question. Saves us clicking around, and also some people can't load those links due to firewall rules.

Comment: You need to explain your problem, which is that a "no method error" exception is raised when the line `num.times {new_str += letter}` is executed. For example, `decode("f1o2d1") #=> NoMethodError (undefined method 'times' for "1":String)`. That's because `num` is a string, yet the class `String` has no instance method `times`. Note that this error message pinpoints the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined a function, but you need to call it or nothing will happen.

As in the example:

```
decode("f1o2d1")
```

However there's a bug in your code when you do that.

Consider using `string.chars` to get the characters and then [`each_slice(2)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to pull out pairs. For example:

```
string.chars.each_slice(2) do |char, count|
  count = count.to_i

  # ... Do stuff with this
end
```

Another trick in Ruby is if you want to repeat a string, multiply it:

```
'a' + 'b' * 2 + 'a'
# => "abba"
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help

Comment: I can't believe it! You wrote, `string.chars.each_slice(2) do ...`. Surely you mean `string.each_char.each_slice(2) do ...`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland They both work, `each_chars` is more efficient. This is an introductory example, mind you, so `chars` is more self-explanatory.

Comment: Candice, `string.chars` returns an array. `string.chars.each_slice(2)` chains the array to the method `Enumerable#each_slice`, returning an enumerator. An enumerator generates objects. Here those objects are passed to a block. `string.each_char.each_slice(2)` does the same thing, except `string.each_char` returns an enumerator, avoiding the creation of the temporary array produced by `string.chars`, saving memory. The rule is to use `chars` if it is chained to an instance method of the class `Array`; use `each_char` if it is chained to a method that accepts an enumerator as its receiver...

Comment: ...but being new to Ruby you don't have to be concerned with that now. Just tuck away that sometimes its best to use `each_char` rather than `chars`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
num = string[i + 1]
num.times {new_str += letter}
```

`string[i + 1]` returns String—in this case a single character that happens to be a number, like `"2"`. `times`, however, is [a method that belongs to the Integer class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-times). In order to use `times` on that number, you need to first convert it to an Integer using `to_i`:

```
num = string[i + 1].to_i
```

With that change your code works perfectly: https://repl.it/@jrunning/CriminalGracefulRefactoring

Comment: I suggest you also mention what happens when `i` equals `string.length - 1`. I suspect that `num` should be set equal to `string[0]` in that case.